# Private and Public usage for the result variable of a Fortran function

Tags: function, fortran, private, public

I think this would have a quick answer from the experts but I have a basic doubt regarding Fortran using modules as private and declaring public what is used.

Would declaring the function in this case, be sufficient to use the module (example 1) and get the result outside?

or,

Does Fortran require to declare public both function and result (example 2)?

Example 1:

```
module forit
    implicit none
    private

    integer, parameter          ::  dp=selected_real_kind(14)
    public                      ::  tester

contains
    function tester(delta,w) result(resval)
        real(dp), intent(in)    ::  delta, w
        real(dp)                ::  resval
        resval  = w / delta ** 2
    end function tester

end module forit
```

Example 2:

```
module forit
    implicit none
    private

    integer, parameter          ::  dp=selected_real_kind(14)
            real(dp)                    :: resval
    public                      ::  tester
    public                      ::  resval

contains
    function tester(delta,w) result(resval)
        real(dp), intent(in)    ::  delta, w
        real(dp)                ::  resval
        resval  = w / delta ** 2
    end function tester

end module forit
```

Comment: Does Example 2 even compile for you?  But going back to your previous question: `resval` doesn't exist in the scope of the module.  It is specific to the function.

Comment: Forgot to add the 'real(dp) :: resval' while copy pasting the code. I edited it now. I wonder what example is the most correct or good practice.

Comment: "Example 2" compiles because resval was also defined in the scope of the module. @mus : as mentioned by francescalus, resval *in the function* and resval *in the module* are two different variables. There is not need to define resval as public, it can just induce confusion because you have an unnecessary variable in the scope of the module. "Example 2" compiles but does not do what you want and is not "good practice" in any way.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for your feedback!